# What happened to my "Close" votes on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

I voted to close some example questions as "off topic" a week or so ago, and now some of my close votes are gone.  Some other questions I've voted to close still show my close vote.  Also, I can't re-vote to close, because I already did.

Is the "vote expiry" on Area 51 incredibly short?  (This doesn't *seem* like the answer, because some of my other close votes are still around, but maybe I just don't accurately remember the order in which I VtCed)

If I need to point out some example questions I voted on, I can, but I'd rather keep my votes anonymous if possible.

EDIT:
Example question is [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living/34170#34170) from the Sustainability Proposal that I (xiaohouzi79) posted as an off-topic example. It also has Flimzy's comment below added at the time the close vote was given.

Comment: "A week or so" sounds about right for the vote expiry to me.  As for anonymity, closed questions show the voters anyways -- or is that different on A51?

Comment: @MatthewRead: If 4 others agree with me that it ought to be closed, the anonynimity isn't as important. If I'm a minority opinion (and I must be in this case), it's a different issue. :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: For some examples see some of my example questions on the [Sustainability proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33364/sustainable-living). Not sure why you are worried about being anonymous because the person who wrote the questions gets notified anywayz. I won't hold it against you ;)

Comment: Had you cast these votes before or after the Area 51 revamp? I've also noticed that behavior, but in my case I think that all these apparently-expired votes were from before the revamp. I absolutely agree that Area51 close votes should not expire, Area 51 doesn't get that much fast-paced scrutiny.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79: That's one example of many, actually. Thanks for not holding it against me, though. :)

Comment: @Gilles: No, I made these votes very recently; well after the revamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the rest of the network, a "close" vote on Area 51 is automatically deleted if

1. The question is still open
2. The question (or proposal in A51's case) has at least 100 views
3. The close vote was cast at least 4 days ago